# Where to place images/CSS in spring-mvc app?

Tags: spring-mvc

I used Netbeans to create a Spring MVC 3.0 app.  I have a simple controller and JSP view.  The JSP view appears correctly except for an image that doesn't render.  My directory structure looks like this:
[image]

In my Home.jsp page, the image that doesn't render is referenced like so:

```
<img src="Images/face.png" />
```

I've verified that face.png is in the Images directory.  So why doesn't it appear in the browser?  In Spring MVC, where should I place files referenced by JSP views, like images, CSS, JS, etc?

Answer (score 37):

Alter your web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/<url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and add below configuration after it:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you have a better solution please share with me.

Comment: @RaviKhakhkhar Can you accept this answer if it worked for you?

Comment: @Drahakar : I haven't asked this question. So naturally I don't have right to accept this answer. I have already up-voted.

Comment: this step does not work for me. I moved image folder outside WEB-INF as stated by [Nada Lu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169266/where-to-place-images-css-in-spring-mvc-app#)

Comment: I have a problem with this... It's all working fine, But when we use bootstrap all the images used by bootstrap is not loading

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find a workable answer here:
[How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something/2001500#2001500)

The problem was that my spring mvc dispatcher servlet was intercepting the calls to static resources.  So I mapped Tomcat's default servlet to handle the static resources.

Answer (score 3):

anything under Web-Inf folder will be marked as private and can not be access by the browser. You suppose to move the image folder outside Web-Inf and under webapp.

Answer (score 1):

For set image in jsp file in Spring MVC framework :

You can simply set your image by following steps:

Step 1. Place images folder in resources

Step 2. write image path  like :
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/logo.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can only reference images/css in the WEB-INF folder. Moving your `Images` folder to WEB-INF should fix your problem.

Comment: That didn't work.  Even trying to directly access the image (http://localhost:8080/myapp/Images/face.png) didn't work.  Do I need to configure spring mvc to enable access to images?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553749/spring-mvc-webapp-where-to-store-paths-to-common-images. Might help.

Comment: No, that confused me even more. :)  What I'm trying to do should be easy w/o resorting to themes.  Perhaps I have URL pattern that's blocking access to anything but controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put all the static data such as image, css, javascripts etc out side the WEB-INF and then call it the normal way :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but let me add my bit here. 
It is generally preferred to hide the .css/ .js files from direct public access by placing them into the main/java/webapp folder instead of the WEB-INF.

The reasons are explained very well in the posts below:

- [What is WEB-INF used for in a Java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786142/what-is-web-inf-used-for-in-a-java-web-application)
- [How to access css/js files in jsps, all of them are placed in WEB-INF??](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/33513-how-to-access-css-js-files-in-jsps-all-of-them-are-placed-in-web-inf) (spring forum)